# Changing variables in onResume void

Tags: android, android-activity

Ok, so the following piece of code is placed in OnResume and seems to cause Force Close. There is another activity (options), that sets all the variables like theme in the database. All I wanted to do is to restore themes and other parameters from the database onResume and therefore change the colors with public voids like SetThemeLight. I just want this thing to work instantly and thought, that onResume is the best way to do that.

```
int Theme = 1;
    Theme = prefs.getInt("theme", Theme);

    switch(Theme){
    case 1:
        SetThemeLight (this);
    break;
    case 2:
        SetThemeBlue (this);        
    break;
    case 3:
        SetThemeDark (this);
    break;
    }
```

And one of the `SetTheme...` methods as an example:

```
public void SetThemeLight (MyActivity myActivity) {
    final EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edit_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}
```

Here is how Options are accessed:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    //options on 'menu' keypress.
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        Intent opt = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
        startActivity (opt);
    };

    return true;
```

Here goes the debugging information:

```
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {net.wswld.dtype.writer/net.wswld.dtype.writer.OptionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at net.wswld.dtype.writer.DTypeActivity.onResume(DTypeActivity.java:109)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
12-23 15:37:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
```

Comment: Have you got a stack trace we can see?

Comment: It's possible that you're trying to set UI properties before they're loaded? You could try using a ViewObserver, which lets you know when the UI component of interest has loaded. Would be really nice to see the error messages from your logcat.

Comment: Now it just suspends with black screen.

Comment: Added the Logcat output. Hope it helps.

Comment: sounds like your edit_text object is null. Why don't you assign that object to a class variable in the OnCreate() method, then refer to it later and do an if(edit_text != null) to check.

Comment: Seems like I found a workaround for my exact case. I read on that and yes, the problem seems to be with onResume and how it is sometimes called with some of the classes being null etc. Anyway, I found a solution of some kind with a simple boolean check. I described it as an answer here.

Comment: PS: `onResume` is a really, really weird thing. I need to read on it, to better understand the way it works and how to avoid cases like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seem to find a workaround.

What I did is to create a simple boolean check in `MainActivity` `onResume`, that checks, whether the Options indeed changed and only then it performs the `switch` part.

If any button is pressed in `OptionsActivity` it commits `opt_changed` boolean to the database and, then in `onResume` it checks it value, before performing the `SetTheme...` methods.

Anyway, thanks to everyone for answers and attention. And I really need to read on Android voids and their behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is that you're sending a final variable to another method. Why are you even sending the EditText? Surely you only need to send the result of edit_text.getText()? You should also be using this arrangement instead of all the if's:

```
switch(Theme){
case 1:
//do something
break;
case 2:
//do something
break;
case 3:
//do something
break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `switch` method — it really comes in handy. I'm not sending anything. Force close happens on pressing the Menu button — when the Options activity is called.

Comment: No problem. You're using  SetThemeLight (edit_text); which means you're sending "edit_text" as a paramater to a method called SetThemeLight?

Comment: Well, `SetThemeLight` used to be `public void SetThemeLight(View view)` and was addressed as `SetThemeLight(edit_text)`. Now, when I changed it to `SetThemeLight(MainActivity mainActivity)` and addressed as `SetThemeLight(this)` - it seems to work. But it's working in OnCreate and requires the app to restart to apply the changes.

Comment: When I put this 'switch' part to the onResume — it force closes on me.

Comment: As soon as I press Menu to access Options.

Comment: what level of sdk are you building for?

Comment: Also, what exception do you get in the logcat?

Comment: I've updated the question to include more details. Level of SDK is set to min=7, max=15 and target is 7.